# Create a select query where if the id is not present then for that id it should return null in SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle

Suppose i have table X having columns a,b and having data like below

[image: a b 1 111 2 222 3 333]

Resultant output i need from query is`select * from X where b in (111,777,888)`

[image]

How to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to build a derived table that holds the values you seach for, and then bring the original table with a `left join`. In SQL Server, you would use `values()`:

```
select v.b, t.*
from (values(111), (777), (888)) v(b)
left join mytable t on t.b = v.b
order by v.b
```

I added a column that holds the value that was intially searched for, since it makes more sense to me - you can remove it if needed.

Oracle does not support this syntax; a (lenghtier) alernative is `union all` and `from dual`:

```
select v.b, t.*
from (
    select 111 b from dual
    union all select 777 from dual
    union all select 888 from dual
) v
left join mytable t on t.b = v.b
order by v.b
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply left join with the same table.

```
SELECT left_x.* 
   FROM x primary_x
   LEFT JOIN X left_x ON primary_x.a = left_x.a AND left_x.b IN ('111', '777', '888')
```

The key here is to us the left-joined table in the select clause (to get the NULLs), and to place the where clause as part of the join statement (to ensure all rows are still present on the primary table).